# Is there a better way to implement a LIKE condition with multiple values using TypeORM?

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

For example, I want to query user, and the conditions:

```
1. age > 20
2. country = "japan" OR country = "singapore"
3. name LIKE '%alex%' OR name LIKE '%jone%'
```

And my where object:

```js
export const multiLikeSqlBuilder = (alias: string, likeList: string[]) => {
  if (likeList.length === 0) {
    return '';
  }

  if (likeList.length === 1) {
    return `(${alias} LIKE '${likeList[0]}')`;
  }

  let sql = '';
  likeList.forEach((like, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      sql = `(${alias} LIKE '${like}'`;
    } else if (index === likeList.length - 1) {
      sql = `${sql} OR ${alias} LIKE '${like}')`;
    } else {
      sql = `${sql} OR ${alias} LIKE '${like}'`;
    }
  });

  return sql;
};

const multiLikeSql = (likeList: string[]) => {
  if (!likeList.length) {
    throw new Error('likeList can not be empty');
  }

  return Raw((alias) => multiLikeSqlBuilder(alias, likeList));
};

const where = {
  age: MoreThan(20),
  country: In(["japan", "singapore"]),
  name: multiLikeSql(["%alex%", "%jone%"]),
};
```

I used the [Raw](https://typeorm.io/find-options) from typeorm, although I don't think this is a good implementation。

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to implement this。